# How to display PowerPoint Presentation In Rails 4 Paperclip??/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

In my application, i have uploaded PPT,PPTX files using paperclip gem. I have url like this

" Presentation.last.avatar.url" = "/system/presentations/avatars/000/000/006/original/example.ppt?1411994371"

Now i want to display those PPT, and PPtx files in my localhost web browser. please give me suggestions.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that you want them to be embedded in the browser, I've solved this by uploading the them to [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/) in the background and then displaying the embedded widget. This is a great solution because turning a PPT file into clean HTML is hard (so let someone else work it out), and you do not have to pay for hosting or bandwidth for those files.

It's a lot nicer to do it this way than to force the user to have an Office plugin installed for their browser, which depending on their platform they may not have.

The [Scribd_fu](https://github.com/shwoodard/scribd_fu) gem will work with Paperclip, or you could use the official [RScribd](https://github.com/scribd/rscribd) gem and roll your own.

Comment: Is it possible to edit uploaded presentation slide by slide using this Scribd?

Comment: No, sadly not. I'm not sure that's really possible using PowerPoint in the browser.